# Equivalence of point estimates in difference-in-difference estimate with varying fixed effects

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I am estimating a simple difference-in-difference model with four countries, ES, FR, DE, and NL. In each country, there are 3 firms. Say I have four time periods, 1, 2, 3 and 4, where ES and FR are treated in period 3 and 4.

Now after creating and indicator variable for $\text{post} \times \text{treated}$, I can estimate the following regression: $outcome = \beta \text{ post} \times \text{treated}$. What is really confusing me is that the point estimates for $\beta$ are the same in this regression irrespective of whether I include country or firm fixed effects.

Why is this the case? As I understand it $\text{post} \times \text{treated}$ is not perfectly collinear with either the country nor the firm fixed effect. I understand that the country fixed effect is a linear combination of the firm fixed effect, and I could not include both in the same regression. However, partialling out everything that is constant for a given firm (firm fixed effect) is not the same as partialling out everythin that is constant for a given country (country fixed effect).

Below is a reproducible example in R.

```
set.seed(532)

rm(list=ls())

df = data.frame(ctry = rep(c("ES", "FR", "DE", "NL"), each = 12), 
                time = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), times = 12), 
                firmid = rep(c(1:12), each = 4))

df$treat = ifelse(df$ctry == "ES" | df$ctry == "FR", 1, 0)
df$post = ifelse(df$time > 2, 1, 0)
df$postXtreat = df$treat * df$post

country_fe = data.frame(ctry = c("ES", "FR", "DE", "NL"), countryfe = abs(rnorm(4)))
firm_fe = data.frame(firmid = c(1:12), firmfe = abs(rnorm(12)))

df = merge(df, country_fe, by = 'ctry')
df = merge(df, firm_fe, by = 'firmid')
df$outcome_raw = rnorm(48)
df$outcome = df$outcome + df$firmfe + df$countryfe

reg_1 = lm(outcome ~ postXtreat + as.factor(firmid), data = df)
summary(reg_1)

reg_2 = lm(outcome ~ postXtreat + as.factor(ctry), data = df)
summary(reg_2)
```